# Парсинг xml документа средствами php и сохранение в БД

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Есть xml такого вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?><DATA FORMAT_VERSION="1.0">
    <record>
        <obl>Бла-бла-бла</obl>
        <region></region>
        <city></city>
        <street></street>
    </record>
    <record>
        <obl>Бла-бла-бла</obl>
        <region>Бла-бла-бла</region>
        <city></city>
        <street></street>
    </record>
    <record>
        <obl>Бла-бла-бла</obl>
        <region>Бла-бла-бла</region>
        <city>Бла-бла-бла</city>
        <street></street>
    </record>
</DATA>
```

Как можно выбрать данные, и сохранить в бд (MySQL), что-бы была связь между ними?

Comment: не соответствует стандарту xml, тег DATA не закрыт, так и должно быть?

Comment: Исправил структуру, вот такая структура документа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция записывает xml стоку в базу, на все поля установлен индекс `UNIQUE`, это немного замедляет работу с базой но зато всю заботу об уникальности записи на себя берет `SQL`:

```
// Отправляет строку и link sql соединения
function str_to_sql($xml_text, $link_sql){
    // Проверяем что xml соответствует стандарту
    if(@simplexml_load_string($xml_text)) {
        // Преобразует в SimpleXMLElement
        $xmls = simplexml_load_string($xml_text);
        // Проходим до всем рекордам
        foreach($xmls as $xml){
            // Формируем запрос
            $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO record (obl, region, city, street) VALUES ('$xml[0]', '$xml[1]', '$xml[2]')";
            // Записываем в базу, в качестве уникального опля берез id_record 
            mysqli_query($link_sql, $insert_sql);
        }
    } else {
        echo "Файл не соответствует стандарту xml".PHP_EOL;
    }
}

// Массив с настройками для доступа к базе данных 
$settings = array(
    'db_host' => 'localhost',
    'db_user' => 'root',
    'db_password' => '1234',
    'db_db_name' => 'bd_name'
);
// Проверяем что подключились к БД
if ((@$link_sql = mysqli_connect($settings['db_host'],
        $settings['db_user'],
        $settings['db_password'],
        $settings['db_db_name']))
    && (@mysqli_query($link_sql, "SET NAMES utf8;")))
{
    // Отправляем в нашу функцию xml и link 
    str_to_sql($xml, $link_sql);
}
```

И записывать все в таблицу, тут установили `UNIQUE` индекс для всех полей и для более быстрого поиска установили индекс на поля и выборка идет по порядку `obl -> region -> city -> street` :

```
CREATE TABLE `record` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `obl` TEXT,
    `region` TEXT,
    `city` TEXT,
    `street` TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY record (obl, region, city, street),
    KEY `index_record` (`obl`(50),`region`(50),`city`(50),`street`(50))
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: "Файл не соответствует стандарту xml ". Скорей всего файл некорректный. А по другому можно вытащить данные?

Comment: Тот файл который вы привели в вопросе - вполне соответствует.

Comment: @motorstorm да, можно находить ошибки в xml, допустим данной функцией xml_error_string, но на данный момент файл в вопросе соответствует стандарту и если вы доверяете получаемым xml файлам то проверку можно и убрать.

Comment: В таблицу попадают и пустые и повторяющиеся значения. Как можно убрать повторение, и загрузить с сохранением связей?

Comment: @motorstorm Тут я предлагаю использовать key при проходке и обрабатывается 1 файл, но  можно средствами mysql не записывать повторяющиеся записи. Допустим создать `UNIQUE KEY record (obl, region, city, street )` и если запись уже есть в таблице она не запишется.

Answer (score 0):

Загрузите свой XML во временную таблицу:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `rawdata` (
    `obl` TEXT, 
    `region` TEXT, 
    `city` TEXT, 
    `street` TEXT);
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'x:\\folder\\filename.xml' 
    INTO TABLE `rawdata` 
    ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<record>';
```

а потом запросами раскидайте по таблицам с сохранением связей.

Comment: А тип TEXT можно заменить на VARCHAR необходимой длины.